# twitter integration in ios using reverse auth

Tags: ios, twitter, twitter-oauth, ios5

Please help me with proper ste by step **tutorial** to integrate **twitter sharing** in my **iphone app** using **reverse auth**. I registered the app in **Twitter** and i have **consumer key**. The information given in this link **https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth** is just not enough.

Comment: Twitter sharing and reverse auth are two different things. Reverse auth is only necessary if you want to retrieve the users auth tokens from Twitter e.g. allowing to implement a "Login with Twitter" feature for logging in to your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Share kit, both follow and Share! check this out

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

Regards

Comment: is it approved by apple? btw i dont wanna use third party frameworks and implement myself.

Comment: You dont need to use it,You can just refer what they have used, you can implement 'Twitter follow' and  'share" with their method easily, the authentication process is simple

Comment: (null): error: /Users/Mindlabs/Downloads/ShareKit-master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Facebook/../../../../../Submodules/facebook-ios-sdk/src/FBDialog.bundle: No such file or directory

Comment: you may not have properly downloaded the  FBconncet folder

Comment: go to Share kit-Shares-Services-Facebook and delete the FBconnect folder from your project .That is needed only for Facebook integration and is not a trusted method too. Twitter part is clean.

Comment: thanks for your support but i'll be using this method > https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone

Comment: Your choice! keep in mind, these APIs are never static, twitter keeps on changing.

Answer (score 0):

Although Share Kit may have worked for you, if you ever ABSOLUTELY needed reverse auth, here is a class to help you accomplish just that with a single method call that returns a dictionary with the token and token secret.

https://github.com/kbegeman/Twitter-Reverse-Auth

Hope this helps!